# rewrite selection using keymap

Tags: input-methods

Is it possible to replace already typed text with the same string parsed by a keymap loaded with `:set keymap`?

For example, assuming there is a keymap that translates `SYM_GROUND` into the unicode `⏚` symbol:

```
loadkeymap
...
SYM_GROUND                        <Char-0x23DA>   " ground
...
```

Is it possible to select the string `SYM_GROUND` in the existing text

```
Ground is denoted with the SYM_GROUND symbol.
```

and have it replaced with `⏚` using the keymap?

I am aware there are substitution engines for these things, but I have a given keymap that I would like to use as is.

Comment: How do you want the replacement done? Change the physical file data or just concealed à la `conceal` via syntax highlighting? One option that comes to mind is to generate the list of substitute or syntax commands from the keymap file and the execute them.

Comment: The replacement should be done physically, just like the normal keymap behaviour, i.e. inserting the unicode glyph `⏚` in the file if the keys `SYM_GROUND` are pressed. Just that I want to simulate "the keys `SYM_GROUND` are pressed" using the text that's already in the file.

Comment: Why do you absolutely want to use a keymap to do that? I think it's not the right tool at all you'll have much less trouble if you use an insert mode mapping or abbreviation. And if the issue is to handle files where are already written a simple substitute command should do the job.

Comment: There is a very huge and intricate keymap available, containing many overlapping definitions such as `SYM_GROUND`, `SYM_G`, `SYM_GROUND_LEFT`, and so on. I do not want to automate the substitution (no way to check if everything went well), but instead I want to be able to go through the many existing, complicated documents, highlight individual tokens and press a magic button to do the substitution. If there is no way to tell vim "take this selection and pretend the keys were pressed" I will indeed make a dictionary lookup, but I thought I might try this first.

Comment: For that, you might generate the relevant regular expression (e.g., assuming they are all word-like and don't contain any special characters: `get_list_of_left_hand_sides()->map({_, v -> printf('\<%s\>', v)})->join('\|')`), search your files with `vimgrep`, and then map a key to a function which looks at the word under the cursor (`expand('<cword>')`, and gets the replacement from the file.